# Why don't these simple Python programs work: Euler 4 and 9

Tags: python

I was trying Project Euler and am stuck on this one:

A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 99.

Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

```
for i in range(1000,100,-1):
    for j in range(1000,100,-1):
        test = i*j
        test = str(test)                #turn product into string
        test2 = test[2:]                #take last two numbers
        test2 = test2[::-1]             #flip them
        if test[:2] == test2:           #if it's a palindrome, the first two should 
            print(i, "\t", j)           #match the flip of last two

input("\n\nPress the ENTER key to exit.")
```

Nothing happens when it is run: the command line calculates, but doesn't print anything.  The program does end though.

I know the bigger numbers have more than just the first and last two numbers, but there should be few enough palindromes that I can just look through them.

Here is the next one:

Find the Pythagorean triplet whose sum is 1000.
a^2 + b^2 = c^2, a+b+c=1000

```
for a in range(1,32):
    for b in range(1,32):
        c = (a**2 + b**2)**.5
        if a + b + c == 1000:
            print(a,"\t",b,"\t",c)
input("\n\nPress the ENTER key to exit.")
```

As with the last program, there is no output...  But again, it does end.
But I noticed that they both have nested for loops. Could this have something to do with it?

Comment: "But I noticed that they both have nested for loops." The human mind is fantastic at finding patterns, but sometimes that ability works against you. Nested loops have nothing to do with your problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both your tests are wrong.  In the first example, the line

```
test2 = test[2:]                #take last two numbers
```

does not say what the comment says – this line strips off the first two characters from the string, leaving only the last digit.  Instead of fixing this line, simply check if the whole string equals the reversed string:

```
if test == test[::-1]:
```

In the second example, you compare approximate floating point numbers to the exact integer `1000`.  Since the floating-pointed numbers will have rounding errors, you don't find an exact match.  See also [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) in the Python tutorial.

You should round `c` to the nearest integer, check if they really are a Pythagorean triple using pure integer arithmetic and *then* test if the sum is 1000.

As pointed out by DSM in the comments, your loops also stop to early.  the maximum sum you will find with these values is about 106.

Comment: While I agree that rounding errors can cause problems in general, it's not the source of the difficulty here.  The OP simply isn't searching high enough.

Comment: @DSM: Right, true as well.  So there are two bugs to fix.

Comment: I think I'd use `c = 1000-a-b` and `if a**2+b**2 == c**2` instead of rounding `c`; that way we always stay in the integers.

Comment: @DSM: I tried to keep as close to the OP's approach as possible.  I'd use the classical parametrization of Pythagorean triples, so I wouldn't even have to check.

Comment: Riight.  I wasn't searching high enough for second one. And for first one, thanks Sven, I tried the if test = test[::-1].

Answer (score 0):

With the second problem: simple mistake;c is a floating point number and you are comparing a+b+c to 1000;raising to a floating point number gives a floating point number e.g. (3**2+4**2)**0.5 == 5.0

Comment: And?  That's not the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For the second problem, you don't have a large enough range.  If the maximum of a and b are 31, then the greatest value of c can be (31^2 + 31^2)^0.5, so the sum of a + b + c you can possibly have is (2 + sqrt(2) * 31, which is less than 1000.

As for the floating point issue, make sure that you use the int() function to turn c into an integer.  This may produce some overlap with rounding errors (I don't think it did for me when I tried that solution), but it should be trivially easy to check the few results you do get for the correct one, even if you do it manually within the one-minute limit.